# angular js http request and MV controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I using angular $http to fire MVC controller to perform query from database. The controller result in DataTable type. The problem a bit wired because when I pass parameter into MVC controller, it wont show the result. But when I hard cord a fixed value then only will render the result. The result is render in ui-view.

```
<tbody>
            @{
                foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                        {
                            <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                        }
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" id="btnView" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="View" style="background-color:#090;color:#000;width:100px;height:20px;">
                        </td>                           
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
```

Above is View

```
public ActionResult FilterMember(string id)
    {
        //wont render the result although has record. (Very sure) 
        SqlParameter[] SqlParam = { new SqlParameter("@Filter", id) };

       // render the result on div (ui-view)
        SqlParameter[] SqlParam = { new SqlParameter("@Filter", "abcd") };
        DataTable dTable = MasterMindDB.dTableSP(DbConn, "SP_Get_MemberList", SqlParam);
        return View("Member", dTable);
    }
```

Above is MVC controller.

```
 myapp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.toggle = function () {
    $http({
        url: "/Admin/FilterMember",
        params: { id: $('#txtsearch').val() }
    });
};
}]);
```

Above is javascript in a JS file

Comment: Why are you using jQuery to populate your parameter? Make use of angulars two-way data binding!

Comment: Your action method is returning a partial view result. It is html markup. But in your code, you are not doing anything with the response coming back from your $http call. Since you are using angular, you might consider returning a json array and use that with `ng-repeat`

Comment: @Daniel Shillcock: I am new in angular. how to bind my result in ui-view?

Comment: `<input type="text" id="btnView"  ng-model="inputValue" />` and then add `$scope.inputValue` to your scope, and then pass that variable in as a parameter. (simplified your input element, the important bit is to add `ng-model="inputValue"` or whatever variable you wish to use, just make sure it's the same as in your controller.